# How to stop random ranges spawning in certain areas that vary?

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am making snake using pygame for a school challenge and it is functional and working but the problem I have is that sometimes when the snake eats the food the new food spawns inside the snake's tail. The reason I'm not sure of how to change this is because the way it generates the random placement of the food is using randomrange on a grid, and I do not know of anyway to exclude the snakes tail from this range/ regenerate it if it does spawn within there. Is this a fundemental problem with using random.randrange or is there a simple fix while retaining most of the code.
Highlighted code top two lines below

```
foodX = round(random.randrange(0,display_width-snake_block)/snake_block)*snake_block
foodY = round(random.randrange(0,display_height-snake_block)/snake_block)*snake_block

import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 600
display_height = 600
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

pureblue = (0,0,255)
purered = (255,0,0)
puregreen = (0,255,0)
red = (125,25,25)
green = (25,125,25)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (1,1,1)
grey = (20,20,20)
darkgrey = (15,15,15)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snake_block = 30
snake_speed = 10

font_style = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)

def user_snake(snake_block, snake_List):
    for x in snake_List:
        pygame.draw.rect(display,green,[x[0],x[1], snake_block, snake_block])

def drawGrid(surf):
    blockSize = snake_block
    surf.fill(grey)
    for x in range(display_width):
        for y in range(display_height):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*blockSize, y*blockSize,blockSize, blockSize)
            pygame.draw.rect(surf,darkgrey, rect, 1)
grid_surf = pygame.Surface(display.get_size())
drawGrid(grid_surf)

def message(msg, colour):
    text = font_style.render(msg, True, colour)
    display.blit(text, [0, display_height/4])

def SnakeGameLoop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False
    X = display_width/2
    Y = display_height/2

    X_change = 0
    Y_change = 0
    
    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1

    foodX = round(random.randrange(0,display_width-snake_block)/snake_block)*snake_block
    foodY = round(random.randrange(0,display_height-snake_block)/snake_block)*snake_block

    while not game_over:
        while game_close == True:
            message("You Lost! Press Q-Quit or C-Play Again", purered)
            pygame.display.update()
 
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        SnakeGameLoop()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    X_change = -snake_block
                    Y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    X_change = snake_block
                    Y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    X_change = 0
                    Y_change = -snake_block
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    X_change = 0
                    Y_change = snake_block

                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    X_change = -snake_block
                    Y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    X_change = snake_block
                    Y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    X_change = 0
                    Y_change = -snake_block
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    X_change = 0
                    Y_change = snake_block

        if X >= display_width or X < 0 or Y >= display_height or Y < 0:
            game_close = True

        X += X_change
        Y += Y_change
        display.blit(grid_surf, (0,0))
        pygame.draw.rect(display, red, [foodX, foodY, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(X)
        snake_Head.append(Y)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)

        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]

        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True

        user_snake(snake_block,snake_List)

        pygame.display.update()

        if X == foodX and Y == foodY:
            foodX = round(random.randrange(0, display_width - snake_block) / snake_block) * snake_block
            foodY = round(random.randrange(0, display_height - snake_block) / snake_block) * snake_block
            Length_of_snake += 1

        clock.tick(snake_speed)


    pygame.quit()
    quit()
SnakeGameLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. One simple way would be to simply generate coordinates, check if they collide with the snake and loop while they don't. While simple, this may be highly inefficient when your snake takes a lot of space on the screen and multiple iterations may be required to place each new item.

Another way would be to generate random coordinates as you do and if they collide with the snake, check for the closest available square around that random point. This may be a bit more involved but should be more efficient. A case may happen where your snake takes a lot of condensed space (say, you went in tight circles for a bit), which may make this case a bit slow as well.

An interesting approach may be to combine both approaches: generate random coordinates, if the square is occupied check for the closest available square at maximum n-square distance and if that doesn't do the trick the generate new coordinates. This might be overkill, however.

Comment: You could also take the difference between the set of all coordinates, and the set of all coordinates currently occupied by the snake. Then, pick a coordinate from that difference.

Comment: Thank you I understand how I could impliment the first one, however how could you do the second. My first thought was to +1 to the X/Y value but Im not really sure if that work